# How to ignore element padding for ::before pseudo element?

Tags: html, css, css-position, pseudo-element

Below is my solution for a pseudo element to ignore the padding, but it feels kind of "hacky" because I used negative margin on the pseudo element.

Is this solution is OK?

I also tried to use `left: 0; top: 0;`, but then I got my pseudo element positioned relative to the body of the page, not the element. Why?

CSS:

```
.block-header {
  background-color: #3A658B;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.block-header::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -10px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #1E3552;
  border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `left: 0` is fine. That's the right method.

Except you haven't specified `position: relative` on the `.block-header` element.

Consider this:

- A pseudo-element is considered a child of its DOM element.
- An absolutely-positioned element is positioned relative to its nearest positioned ancestor.
- When there is no positioned ancestor, the abspos element is positioned relative to the initial container (i.e., the HTML element / viewport).

```css
.block-header {
  background-color: #3A658B;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  position: relative;      /* NEW */
}

.block-header::before {
  left: 0;                 /* NEW */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #1E3552;
  border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-header">test</div>
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning) for more information.